# R: How can I extract a specific value from a column into a new column?

Tags: r

I am new to programming and I have a problem in R. I have a table in which there is one column ("Comment") that contains text separated with commas or questionmarks. I need to search this column for a specific word ("counter clockwise"), extract it and put it into a new column.
This is the head of the table:

```
 PictureStoneID Place_Name Reference_Name Clockwise Comment        X     Y    
##             <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>          <lgl>     <chr>          <chr> <chr>
##  1              4          4 Navarra 12     FALSE     13 arms? Midd~ -2,8~ 42,7~
##  2              6          4 Navarra 14     FALSE     middle circe,~ -2,8~ 42,7~
##  3             12          8 Soria 3        FALSE     Little lines ~ -3,3~ 41,7~
##  4             13          9 Soria 13       TRUE      circle inside~ -3,0~ 41,5~
##  5             14         11 Soria 15       TRUE      circle outsid~ -2,5~ 41,8~
##  6             23         16 Ire I          TRUE      triangles out~ 18,8~ 57,7~
##  7             24         16 Ire IV         TRUE      round rays, f~ 18,8~ 57,7~
##  8             25         16 Ire 7          FALSE     middle or bot~ 18,8~ 57,7~
##  9             26         17 Kyrka I        TRUE      triangles ins~ 18,4~ 57,6~
## 10             27         17 Kyrka II       TRUE      triangles ins~ 18,4~ 57,6~
```

I tried the filter() function but that one only gives me rows which ONLY contain "counter clockwise" and nothing else.

```
data %>%
  filter(Comment == "counter clockwise")
```

I also tried the separate() function but it separated the data from the column randomly. I was not able to specificly pick "counter clockwise" and extract it into a new column.

```
data %>%
  separate(col = Comment,
    into = c("Comment", "Direction"))
```

I tried a couple of other things but they did not work either.
Can anyone help me with this? I am quite frustrated and don't know what to do. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you want a column that indicated whether "counter clockwise" exists in the string in the Comment column.

This would create a new logical column named key_word that indicates if the pattern is or not present in the string:

```
library(tidyverse)
    
data <- 
  data %>%
  dplyr::mutate(key_word = stringr::str_detect(Comment, "counter clockwise"))
data                        # dataframe with logical key_word column 

data %>%
  dplyr::filter(key_word)   # filter only to rows that contain "counter clockwise"
```

Comment: Thanks, Claudiu!
Unfortunately, I get the following error message:
Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Comment: Sorry for late answer. Both version of the code work now, but nothing is happening. It just shows me the table as it was before.

Comment: Yes, it is the same dataframe, but it has an additional column named `key_word`. If you want to filter the dataframe to only rows that contain "counter clockwise" you would simply pipe further into filter `%>% dplyr::filter(key_word)`

Comment: My bat, now I see it. That's a great solution to the problem! Thanks a lot, I can work with this!

Comment: If it solves your problem, please consider accepting the answer so others may have an indication that it was properly addressed. Welcome to SO and good luck with your analyses.